# Track Appointment Time changes in Office add-ins

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office-app

I am currently opening a new Appointment form from add-in commands using " Office.context.mailbox.displayNewAppointmentForm " .

And it is working fine. But I want to track if there are any changes made to the newly opened Appointment. I tried to use item.start.getAsync() and item.end.getAsync() , but it still doesn't fetch me the times so that I can compare if there is any change.

Also tried to look into AppointmentTimeChanged event. But still no luck.

Is it possible to track these changes ?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere here that you have to call `.saveAsync()` first in order to get the updated appoinment  with `.getAsync()`, but don't quote me on this one.
Adding a change-event handler is not possible AFAIK.

Comment: Currently there is no way to track the changes. Since you opened the add-in for older appointment, the add-in only has context of that window. If you want to track the changes for the new appointment window, you need to open the add-in for that.